# How to keep processes alive after exiting git bash for windows?

Tags: git-bash

- Given I start git bash and then start window processes in the background like "C:\MyProgram.exe &"
- When I exit
- Then all processes are closed

Is it possible to close the window and keep them alive?

---

My use case is that I want to automate the startup of multiple programs (using bash scripts).

Answer (score 0):

Using `nohup` or `disown` solves this issue, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4006/309309

This is not a problem specific to `git bash`, but for any unix terminal.